# How do I render a PDF from HTML with working named anchors?

Tags: pdf, phantomjs, pdf-generation, rendering

Is there a way for a bunch of named anchors in a large html to be clickable within a PhantomJs generated PDF file?

I.e. say I have a table of contents or a list of FAQ questions. When clicking on the question/title - I'm taken to its answer/content within the same HTML file which is great but when the same HTML is rendered into a PDF each named anchor becomes an absolute URL (i.e. http://example.com/render.html#anchor_1) so clicking on it opens a browser with that URL instead of jumping to its content within the PDF file.

So, basically, is it possible (and how?) for a markup like this - https://fiddle.jshell.net/jyjuaaog/ to work within the generated PDF?

BTW, this works great when "printing as a PDF file" in Google Chrome but links end up broken when rendered in PhantomJs so there must be something I'm missing that I can't seem to find in the docs.

Any ideas?

Thanks!﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [there's a bug in PhantomJs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13959) preventing this. As [suggested by PhantomJsCloud](https://plus.google.com/105662810354906241772/posts/5dpBNMYvqWT) a quick-and-dirty workaround would be to replace the links with page links.